# C++ undefined reference to `Class::Ctor'

Tags: c++, class, oop, header

I have this error massage

> In function 'int main()':|
>    unused variable 'Bobi' 
>   In function `main':|
>
> undefined reference to `Student::Student()'|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|

Can you help me to fix this problem and check my method declaration

This is my **main.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Student *Bobi= new Student();

    return 0;
}
```

This is my **header**

```
    #ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>

class Student
{
    public:
        Student();
        virtual ~Student();
        std::string getName()
        {
            return this->name;
        }
        void setName(std::string name)
        {
            this->name=name;
        }
        int getNumber()
        {
            return this->number;
        }
        void setNumber(int number)
        {
            this->number=number;
        }
        std::string getSurname()
        {
            return this->surname;
        }
        void setSurname(std::string surname)
        {
            this->surname=surname;
        }
        double setDiploma1(double diploma1)
        {
            return this->diploma1;
        }
        void getDiploma1()
        {
            this->diploma1=diploma1;
        }
        double setDiploma2(double diploma2)
        {
            return this->diploma2;
        }
        void getDiploma2()
        {
            this->diploma2=diploma2;
        }
        double setIzpit1(double izpit1)
        {
            return this->izpit1;
        }
        void getIzpit1()
        {
            this->izpit1=izpit1;
        }
        double setIzpit2(double izpit2)
        {
            return this->izpit2;
        }
        void getIzpit2()
        {
            this->izpit1=izpit2;
        }
        double Bal(double setDiploma1,double setDiploma2,double setIzpit1,double setIzpit2)
        {
            double bal=setDiploma1+setDiploma2+setIzpit1+setIzpit2;
            return bal;
        }
    protected:
    private:
        int number;
        std::string name;
        std::string surname;
        double diploma1;
        double diploma2;
        double izpit1;
        double izpit2;
};

#endif // STUDENT_H
```

**Student.cpp**

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Student::Student()
{
}
Student::~Student()
{
}
```

Comment: What is your makefile or command you use to compile this?

Comment: How do you *build* your project? Are you sure you build with the `Student.cpp` source file? It has to be in the *project* in your IDE, not only in the directory on the disk.

Comment: It is in my project in my IDE

Comment: I build it and then I run it.

Comment: Not to talk about your current errors while trying to build, but why don't your `set` functions have any parameters ? You set the class member to itself... a little strange isn't it ?

Comment: If it's really in your IDE project, then it should have been built and you should not have the linker error. Try rebuilding the project, and look at *all* the build output. Does it tell you the `Student.cpp` file is being built?

Comment: No Student.cpp is not build.How to build it?

Comment: If it's not being built then you can't really have it in the IDE project. What IDE are you using? You need to add the file to the projects "Sources" (or similar) folder *in the IDE project*, it's not enough that it's just on the disk in the same directory, it actually have to be inside the IDE so you can see it together with the other source files. And if you see it in the IDE, are you looking at a *directory* view and not a *project* view?

Comment: I am using CodeBlocks. In Manager->Projects and there in project Sources i have main.cpp and Student.cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete Student.cpp file completely, then run with using some set get in main. RUN now

It should work. Look student.cpp should header bjt you dont even need it jusr define constructor in destructor in header file that you have.bc virtual using is wrong